# fortran: Identify intrinsic type of a variable *after* the variable is in memory

Tags: fortran, introspection

I am a bit new to fortran, coming to it from the Python, R and SAS.  In all of these languages, data type formatting is embedded in output functions, but fortran requires (among other things) an explicit format indicator for each variable being written.  I'd like to dynamically build the format string by leveraging variable introspection to have fortran tell me what the data type is, along with the applicable attributes (KIND, LEN, etc).  Such introspection would also assist in the construction of universally applicable program subunits.

In the OO world of Python and R, this is a trivial inquiry.  For example, testing whether a value is a string in Python is just...

```
isinstance('foo',basestring)
```

There are other methods of course.  In any event, I just can't shake the idea that such an intrinsic inquiry must exist in fortran.  To date, all I have seen are methods that would be unable to distinguish between a whole real value and integers.

Others have proposed using the `IOSTAT` parameter in the `READ` statement.  I have not yet figured out how to leverage this statement for variables that already exist in memory.  (At this point, I have only encountered use of the `READ` statement in conjunction with reading from the keyboard or a file on the hard drive.)

Someone please tell me I have made an egregious oversight somewhere.  I feel like this capability has to exist.  Thanks.

Comment: What about bundling routines/functions for the individual types using an `interface`?

Comment: Why do you not use g (or g0) descriptor?

Comment: The generic interface would work, though I do no think it is necessary. I don't know what the OP means with `IOSTAT`.

Comment: The `READ` statement has an `IOSTAT` argument that is set to values other than zero in the event of an error during input (the exact number depends on the error and processor).  It is useful in this context because you can specify the format of the information being input.  For example, if you specify `'(i10)'`, and the input value is not an integer, `IOSTAT` will take a non-zero value.

Comment: Also, you are correct that this operation is not *necessary*.  I could definitely explicitly write out each format (in multiples where applicable).  I just don't want to sift through it if I have hundreds of variables.  I want to write something that will let fortran do the heavy (read: tedious) lifting.

Comment: Here is a case where you'd be best off to explain what you are actually trying to accomplish.  Simple list directed (*) io (including internal io) handles the intrinsic types without you worrying about formatting.

Comment: @george sure, but I expected he cannot use it. There are places you need the explicit format, e.g., non-advancing i/o, printing a nice table and so on. But I will add it to my answer.

Comment: @george  I did at least attempt to explain it in the original posting (the whole bit about building a format string for output).  It appears I did not do a great job.  Thanks for your input.  I initially was trying to create a nice table, but maybe I can just get away with embedding commas and letting * handle the formatting nonsense?  Also, again, this kind of introspection could have utility in building functions and subroutines that may receive multiple data types.

Comment: So, I still actually have an application for this.  The list directed output is useful, but sometimes it only gets me partially towards the correct format.  I would like to be able to use it to explicitly identify formats for some of the variables, while retaining the explicit format strings for others.  For example, I have a set that I am reading in that contains one `REAL` followed by 3 `INTEGER`s.  The integers are single digit, but for some reason when I explicitly specify them as `'3I1'`, I get incorrect numbers.  How can I find out what format fortran is implicitly using?

Answer (score 5):

This capability does not exist. You always know what type is the variable you are working with. At least the declared type. With polymorphic types you must use `select type` to get the actual type, but again you know the type at compile time then.

You can use the `gw.d` or `g0` descriptor for universal formatting of intrinsic types. You do not need to think what type of number it belongs to. For user defined derived types there is a possibility to define own I/O routines.

For very simple I/O you can use the list-directed I/O, e.g.,

```
print *, x
read(*,*) x
write(*,*) x
```

There are some restrictions on when you can use it and you don't have much control of the behavior.

Otherwise I do not think this capability is something that obviously must be present in an OO language. Both languages you mean (R, Python) are dynamically typed and therefore have much larger need for this. In C++98 there is `typeid()` but most people do not need it.

Comment: Interesting, `g` did not show up as a format option in either of my fortran texts.  I didn't even know to look for it.  You are, of course, correct that you know the type if you declared the variable.  Knowing the type isn't the real issue I am trying to solve.  I am attempting to build a format string for writing to CSV *without* have to manually specify each variable being written.                  Just so I understand the `g` formatter, I can use this to describe any numeric intrinsic input when writing to disk, and it will pass the appropriate type (integer vs real)?

Comment: Yes `g` can be used for every intrinsic type (including all numerical ones). It was actually part of Fortran 77 already, though `g0` is Fortran 2008.

Comment: `g` has been around a long time.  When it became valid of all types is a good question but it seems f90. If you have an old f77 book it will only show usage with floats.